# Hero image behind body content

Tags: html, css

For some reason my hero-image falls behind my body-content. How to fix so that the hero-image pushes my body-content down. I tried `z-index` but that did not work (my hero-images have variable auto-heights).

```css
.hero .hero-bg, .hero {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.hero .hero-bg {
 background-image:url('http://via.placeholder.com/1000x300');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: red;
}

body {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
<section class="hero">
<div class="hero-bg">
</div>
</section>
<section class="content">
<p> content - content - content - content - content - content - content - content - content - content - content - content - content</p>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: What content, theres nothing else

Comment: That “some reason” is called absolute positioning … Either don’t position the element absolutely, or give body/the actual content an appropriate padding-top. (You might want to remove `height: 100%`, in general - that will easily lead to other problems. The state-of-the-art way to get an element to be as high as the viewport is `100vh`, and that doesn’t need a height set on every parent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are giving your image `position: absolute;`, so it will fall behind other content.

I added some extra content in the HTML so it is clear that the rest doesn't overlap your `.hero` section:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: red;
}

body {
  background-color: green;
}

.hero,
.hero-bg,
.content {
  height: 100%;
}

.hero-bg {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1000x300');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center 80%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero-bg"></div>
</section>

<section class="content">
  <div>Other content</div>
</section>
```